# Assigning Value(s) to ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, iteration, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to assign a value onto a ManyToMany field in the Order class.

```
def assign_order(request, user_id):
    order_id = request.session.get('order_id')
      #picking this session from a previous fxn allowing me to call the order.id
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)

    employee = Employee.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
      #Employee is a profile model leveraging an AbstractUser

    order.deliverer.set(employee)
      #using .set() for direct assignment of user(Employee) onto ManyToMany field on "Order"
    order.status = 'deliverer_assigned'
    order.save()
```

The problem with this schema is that the fxn will always overwrite my ManyToMany field rather than append a new User(Employee profile) onto it.

**1. Is there a better way of accomplishing what I need? i.e. Updating a ManyToMany field outside the admin?**

**2. How do I prevent the overwrite problem in this scenario?**

Comment: you wanna add an item to ManyToMany field in your views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

`order.deliverer.add(employee)`

rather than `.set` should work.

See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. I've found I need a small change to prevent a ProgrammingError:
<<subquery must return only one column>>...
order.service_provider.add(*employee)

Comment: @Magere

Do you expect employee to be a single employee or a list? If you expect a list your edit is right, but if you expected a single employee change this: `Employee.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)` to `Employee.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).first()` as filtering always returns a QuerySet instead of a single query.

Comment: Agreed. Also I could simply call on get_object_or_404 rather than filter.